# API 2.0 is not returning Programmers in list of sites

Tags: bug, status-norepro, api-v2, sites

Run `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/sites`.
programmers.stackexchange.com is not in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it in the response, perhaps you're not paging far enough to see it?

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/sites?pagesize=200

```
...
{
  site_type: "main_site",
  name: "Programmers",
  logo_url: "http://sstatic.net/programmers/img/logo.png",
  api_site_parameter: "programmers",
  site_url: "http://programmers.stackexchange.com",
  audience: "professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development",
  icon_url: "http://sstatic.net/programmers/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
  aliases: [
    "http://programmer.stackexchange.com"
  ],
  site_state: "normal",
  styling: {
    link_color: "#0077CC",
    tag_foreground_color: "#5D5D5D",
    tag_background_color: "#FFF"
  },
  closed_beta_date: 1283299200,
  open_beta_date: 1283904000,
  launch_date: 1292457600,
  favicon_url: "http://sstatic.net/programmers/img/favicon.ico",
  related_sites: [
    {
      name: "Programmers Meta",
      site_url: "http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com",
      relation: "meta",
      api_site_parameter: "meta.programmers"
    },
    {
      name: "Chat Stack Exchange",
      site_url: "http://chat.stackexchange.com",
      relation: "chat"
    }
  ],
  twitter_account: "StackProgrammer",
  markdown_extensions: [
    "Prettify"
  ]
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize there were so many sites they were being paged. There should be a pagesize=infinity for this call

Comment: @Adam there isn't a limit on the `pagesize` of the `/sites` endpoint of version 2.2, for which I use 999 to retrieve all sites.